# Xcode: How to add new language to existing Localizable.string

Tags: xcode, xcode7

In Xcode 7
I have created a `Localizable.string` and in Inspector I can only see two languages - how do I add more?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:

In Project settings under "info" you can add additions languages.

Answer (score 0):

Select Name project in PROJECT, Info, Localizations, and press "+" to add language.

[image]

After, you can select the Resource File.

[image]

Then, you can modify the Localizable.strings(new-language) created with your translations and Build to verify possible errors.

[image]